# Cohomology of compact complex nilmanifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology

Given a simply connected nilpotent real Lie group $G$ and a discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ such that the nilmanifold  $G/\Gamma$ is a compact complex manifold.

Is there any way to calculate (de Rahm) cohomologies of $G/\Gamma$? By Nomizu theorem:  $H^p(G/\Gamma,\mathbb R)\cong H^p(\mathfrak g,\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Is this a question about how to compute Lie algebra cohomology? Chevalley-Eilenberg

Comment: Yes indeed. . Is that possible?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology the complex and differential is explicit

Comment: There is a lot of literature on the cohomology for nilpotent Lie algebras. For trivial coefficients, its dimensions are the Betti numbers.

Comment: The question mark after Nomizu's theorem is confusing, since it's an affirmation. Also the title does not match the question.

Comment: Indeed Nomizu's theorem reduces to computation of Lie algebra cohomology (so the answer does not depend on $\Gamma$, unlike, say the (co)homology with $Z/p$ coefficients for small $p$.). The definition of the latter is more than "explicit", it's computable by standard linear algebra since it's the cohomology of a sequence of finite-dimensional spaces with coboundary map that are explicit in terms of the bracket.